# Displaying a custom bars/ribbons chart while collapsing bars to utilize fewer lines

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, filtering

I am working on a bar chart displaying time intervals.

[image]

The intervals are defined events objects, which have a unique `id` and two days `start` and `end`.

The rule is to display one line if events never overlap eg when ordered, the start of event X is never before the end of event X-1.

If there are overlaps, we add the minimum necessary number of lines to display bars so there are no overlaps on the graph, and we want graphs with later `start` be above the ones with earlier start-date, yet not by violating the first rule.

I did the following:

```
const doesOverlap = (events, event) => {
  let does = false;
  events.forEach(e => {
    if (
      e.id !== event.id &&
      event.dayEnd - e.dayStart > 0 &&
      event.dayStart - e.dayEnd > 0
    ) {
      does = true;
    }
  });
  return does;
};

// tough to write a normal function
// let's try recursive for now
const levelEvents = (events, level) => {
  let ret;
  if (level === 0) {
    ret = events.filter(
      (event, i) =>
        !doesOverlap(events, event) ||
        (doesOverlap(events, event) && !events[i + 1]) ||
        (doesOverlap(events, event) &&
          !!events[i + 1] &&
          !doesOverlap(events, events[i + 1])),
    );
  } else {
    const previous = levelEvents(events, level - 1);
    const remaining = events.filter(
      ({ id }) => previous.filter(e => e.id === id).length === 0,
    );
    ret = levelEvents(remaining, level - 1);
  }
  return ret;
};
```

I calculate the number of overlaps in my set as:

```
const getOverlaps = events => {
  const sortedEvents =
    events?.length > 0 ? events.sort((a, b) => a.dayStart - b.dayStart) : [];
  // the maximum number of overlaps for any ribbon internal in the set
  let maxOverlaps = 0;
  sortedEvents.forEach((element, i) => {
    let overlaps = 0;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < sortedEvents.length; j++) {
      // intervals are sorted
      if (
        !!sortedEvents[i + j] &&
        element.dayEnd - sortedEvents[i + 1].dayStart >= 0
      ) {
        overlaps++;
      }
    }
    maxOverlaps = Math.max(maxOverlaps, overlaps);
  });
  return maxOverlaps;
};
```

I am not too happy with the `for` loop, because of the scope/binding. Yet, it seems to be working.

Then I calculate the total number of lines with:

```
let totalOverlaps = 0;
data.forEach(ribbon => {
  const events = ribbonEvents[ribbon.id];
  totalOverlaps = Math.max(getOverlaps(events), totalOverlaps);
});
```

then I draw multiple ribbon lines as:

```
              {data.map((ribbon, order) => {
                 const events = ribbonEvents[ribbon.id];
                 const overlaps = getOverlaps(events);

                 const rbs = new Array(overlaps + 1).fill(ribbon);
                 return rbs.map((ribbon, level) => {
                   return (
                     <RibbonChart
                       key={ribbon.id}
                       ...
                       ribbon={ribbon}
                       ribbonEvents={ribbonEvents[ribbon.id]}
                       ...
                       level={level}
                     />
                   );
                 });
               })}
```

Inside the chart gets `levelEvents` from `ribbonEvents` and `level`.

Currently, level events are not picked correctly. Hence the chart depicted has an overlap of a red and blue bars. We picked the bar with the latest start date for the top bar, while we should have picked the blue one and placed the bar from the top line into the second one.

How could I efficiently rewrite my `levelEvents()`, so the chart would look right - a blue bar in the top line and two red bars in the bottom line?

Comment: If I read correctly, this is the fairly well-known problem of Interval Partitioning.  [This article](http://www.algorithmsandme.com/interval-partitioning-problem/) has solutions in Java and Python, and should be easy enough to translate.  [This one](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/04GreedyAlgorithms-2x2.pdf) (see the second section) also has a nice description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is the fairly well-known problem of Interval Partitioning.  Here is a fairly simple version of it.

```js
const partitionIntervals = (intervals) =>
  [...intervals] 
    .sort (({dayStart: a}, {dayStart: b}) => a - b) 
    .reduce ((gs, interval) => {
      let group = gs .find (g => g .end <= interval .dayStart) 
      if (!group) {group = {events: []}; gs .push (group)}
      group .events .push (interval)
      group .end = interval .dayEnd
      return gs
    }, [{end: -Infinity, events: []}])
    .map (g => g.events)

const intervals = [{ id: 'A', dayStart:  7, dayEnd: 10 }, { id: 'B', dayStart:  1, dayEnd:  6 }, { id: 'C', dayStart: 11, dayEnd: 15 }, { id: 'D', dayStart: 15, dayEnd: 18 }, { id: 'E', dayStart: 13, dayEnd: 18 }, { id: 'F', dayStart:  1, dayEnd: 10 }, { id: 'G', dayStart: 11, dayEnd: 14 }, { id: 'H', dayStart:  1, dayEnd:  6 }, { id: 'I', dayStart:  6, dayEnd: 12 }, { id: 'J', dayStart: 16, dayEnd: 20 }]

console .log (partitionIntervals (intervals))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

It is less efficient than we would want for large sets.  We could fix that by keeping instead of our array of groups, a priority queue of them.  If your data warrants it, it shouldn't be too hard to use a queue prioritized by end times of the groups, and then instead of searching with `find`, just check if the current interval starts on or after the end time of the top group, adding a new group to the queue otherwise.

### Update

The implementation above was bothering me.  This does the same thing without all the mutation:

```js
const partitionIntervals = (intervals) =>
  [...intervals] 
    .sort ((a, b) => a .dayStart - b .dayStart) 
    .reduce (
      ([g, ...gs], interval) => 
        (interval.dayStart < g .end
          ? [g, ... gs, {end: interval.dayEnd, events: [interval]}]
          : [{end: interval.dayEnd, events: [... g.events, interval]}, ...gs]
        ) .sort ((a, b) => a .end - b .end), 
      [{end: -Infinity, events: []}]
    )
    .map (g => g.events)
    
const intervals = [{ id: 'A', dayStart:  7, dayEnd: 10 }, { id: 'B', dayStart:  1, dayEnd:  6 }, { id: 'C', dayStart: 11, dayEnd: 15 }, { id: 'D', dayStart: 15, dayEnd: 18 }, { id: 'E', dayStart: 13, dayEnd: 18 }, { id: 'F', dayStart:  1, dayEnd: 10 }, { id: 'G', dayStart: 11, dayEnd: 14 }, { id: 'H', dayStart:  1, dayEnd:  6 }, { id: 'I', dayStart:  6, dayEnd: 12 }, { id: 'J', dayStart: 16, dayEnd: 20 }]

console .log (partitionIntervals (intervals))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This version sorts the list of groups on each iteration of the `reduce` callback.  Again, a priority queue would improve the performance if your lists are long, but at a cost of code complexity.